# MySQL - Trigger that will automatic insert on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

How can I create a trigger that will insert data into another table.

For example: I have a `department` table and a `course` table and the `course` table has a foreign key named `department_id`.
I insert `CICCT` into the `course` table but there is no `CICCT` in the `department` table.
My goal is to make the trigger add the value in the  `department` table. How can I do this?
I tried this, is this correct?

```
CREATE TRIGGER department_insert BEFORE INSERT 
ON course 
FOR EACH row 
begin 
  INSERT INTO department 
              (department_id, 
               description) 
  VALUES      (new.id_dep, 
               NULL); 
end;
```

Another question in the same subject, what do I need to do in order reduce the room capacity by one when a student enrolls?

Comment: hello anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger might look like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER department_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON course
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT IGNORE INTO department (department_id, description)
  VALUES (NEW.id_dep, NULL);
```

**Note:**

- to access column values of a row being inserted you have to use the `NEW` keyword

  ```
  NEW.id_dep
  ^^^
  ```
- use `IGNORE` clause in `INSERT` to ignore `department_id` values if they already exist in `department` table. It allows to greatly streamline your code.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/093e2/1)** demo

*Make a separate post for your second question and specify table schemas*

Comment: btw do you know my another question on the lower... where it reduce by one every insert... and reduce one on new and add one on old... like changing subject...

Comment: @JeraldPunx You're quite welcome. I'm glad I could help :) Now to help you with your second question like, I said, post another question on StackOverflow and I or another SO members will be happy to help you. And make sure that you post table schemas (structure) for that question. If you want you can leave me a comment with a link to your new question when you create it.